# Plotting interaction in R graphs

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, lattice, interaction

I have following type of data (although number of data points is very large)

```
# property data
name <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
diameter <- c(4.3, 8.3,1.2, 3.3)
X <- c( 1, 2, 3, 4)
Y <- c(1, 3, 3, 4)
colr <- c(10, 20, 34, 12)
propdata <- data.frame (name, diameter, X, Y, colr)


# interaction data
name1 <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B")
name2 <- c("B", "C", "D", "C", "D")
score <- c(1.1, 2.2, 5.4, 3.1, 2.0)
relation <- data.frame (name1, name2, score)
```

I want to create a graph similar to following, such that it has following property.

(

```
1) diameter of circles is governed by propdata$diameter 
(2) Position in xy field is governed by cordinates of propdata$X and propdata$y 
(3) Fill color of the circle is controlled by propdata$colr 
 (4) Interaction is governed by relation data.frame, name1 
  and name2 elements will be connected and weight of the line is govenmened 
  by relation$score.
```

[image]

Is it possible to make such graph with existing R base or any popular graphics software or need a more specialized software.

EDITS:

This is as far as I go using bubble plot:

```
 p <- ggplot(propdata, aes(X,Y,size = diameter, label=name))
p <- p + geom_point(colour= "red")+geom_text(size=3) # colour = colr does not work 
p
```

[image]

Comment: The answer is yes. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried ggplot2 not singificant ..used geom_point () just to frame the buble size, do not know how to connect ...

Comment: @Andrie see my edits, that is as far as I go, I tried...thank you .

Comment: This was harder than I thought initially.  Answer posted and edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is something I cooked up quickly with `qgraph`:

```
library("qgraph")

plot(1,type='n',xlim=c(min(propdata$X)-0.5,
    max(propdata$Y)+0.5),ylim=c(min(propdata$Y)-0.5,max(propdata$Y)+0.5),
    xlab="",ylab="")

col <- rgb(0,1-propdata$colr/max(propdata$colr),0)

qgraph(relation,plot=FALSE,rescale=FALSE,layout=as.matrix(propdata[c("X","Y")]),
        edge.color="darkred",color=col,propdata$colr,directed=FALSE,esize=10,
       vsize=propdata$diameter+2,lcolor="white",curve=c(0,0,-0.2,0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer....it is quite nice !! I looked at the qgraph webpage https://sites.google.com/site/qgraphproject/examples ...which is quite nice ...

Comment: +1 Very nice. My to-do list of new things to learn is growing by the day.

Comment: Thanks! If the position of the nodes isn't important I would just use a force embedded algorithm instead. Also default colors for edges work better, but they are green:)

Answer (score 3):

So, the problem is creating a line plot that represents the interaction.

To do this, you need to format your data in the appropriate form.  You want to plot segments, and for this you need the co-ordinates of each segment in a single row in your data frame:

```
interaction <- merge(propdata, relation, by.x="name", by.y="name1")
interaction <- cbind(interaction, 
               merge(propdata, relation, by.x="name", by.y="name2")[, c("X", "Y")])
names(interaction)[8:9] <- c("Xend", "Yend")
interaction

  name diameter X Y colr name2 score Xend Yend
1    A      4.3 1 1   10     B   1.1    2    3
2    A      4.3 1 1   10     C   2.2    3    3
3    A      4.3 1 1   10     D   5.4    3    3
4    B      8.3 2 3   20     C   3.1    4    4
5    B      8.3 2 3   20     D   2.0    4    4
```

Now we run into another problem.  In `ggplot2`, you can only have a single size scale. Since you have a size argument for both the point and line, that really represents two things, this can't be done without a workaround.

Thus the workaround is to manually draw the circles using `geom_polygon`.

Construct the data frame with circles:

```
circle <- function(x, y, d, color, scale=1){
  d <- d * scale
  angle <- seq(-pi, pi, length = 50) 
  data.frame(
    x = x + d/2*sin(angle), 
    y = y + d/2*cos(angle),
    color=color)
}

circles <- ddply(propdata, .(name), 
                 function(x)with(x, circle(X, Y, diameter, colr, scale=0.2)))
```

Finally, create the plot:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=circles, aes(group=name, x=x, y=y, fill=color)) +
  geom_text(data=propdata, aes(x=X, y=Y, label=name), hjust=0, vjust=0) +
  geom_segment(data=interaction, aes(x=X, y=Y, xend=Xend, yend=Yend, size=score)) + 
  scale_size("Inter", to=c(0, 5)) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Comment: pretty nice...only thing I would like to put label a little far from the circle center ...thanks for the answer ...

Comment: .also can we control line size as sometime becomes so bold that it is informative but not pretty ..thanks for the answer ...